# C Updating of Arrays

Tags: arrays, c, sorting

with reference to this question - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/arrange-given-numbers-form-biggest-number-set-2/

For some reason, if I do not update the elements in the second array, the elements in the first array does not get updated correspondingly.

```
int array[] = {1, 34, 3};

int newArrayWithSamePower[3] = {11, 34, 33};

// Sort initial array based on power array elements
for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j <= 2; j++) {
        if (newArrayWithSamePower[j] > newArrayWithSamePower[i]) {
            int temp2 = newArrayWithSamePower[i];
            newArrayWithSamePower[i] = newArrayWithSamePower[j];
            newArrayWithSamePower[j] = temp2;

            // Unsure why array indexes go haywire if you dont update power array
            int temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[j];
            array[j] = temp;
            
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i <= tempIndex; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", array[i]);
}
```

Expected output: {34, 3, 1}

However, if I do not update the power array, the output will become {3, 1, 34}.

Comment: If you want to update array called `array` why do you check element in `powerArray` in `if` statement?

Comment: the usage of `tempIndex` looks really odd... Please provide a proper [mre]

Comment: apologies about that, i'm quite new to this platform @AnttiHaapala

Comment: i'm trying to sort the array based on the size of the elements in the 2nd array based on their indexes @LazarĐorđević

Comment: @JeraldLim please [edit] the question and have an entire self-standing example in there.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala hello, i've added a link reference to the question i'm trying to solve

Comment: `Expected output: {34, 3, 1}` There is no `printf` in your code, there is no output. [I get 34 3 1 godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/6vx8qn). Which one is the "power array"? What do you mean by "not update the power array"? Ach, if you do not swap elements inside the `newArrayWithSamePower`, then the condition `if (newArrayWithSamePower[j] > newArrayWithSamePower[i])` is going to be true on different indexes. Take a paper and a pen and go through the algorithm.

Comment: @KamilCuk omg you're right, i must update the elements in ``newArrayWithSamePower`` so that it does not be true on every single interation. thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @KamilCuk hi, isit okay if you post your comment as an answer so i can upvote you? :) appreciate the help once again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    if (newArrayWithSamePower[j] > newArrayWithSamePower[i]) {
        int temp2 = newArrayWithSamePower[i];
        newArrayWithSamePower[i] = newArrayWithSamePower[j];
        newArrayWithSamePower[j] = temp2;
```

If you do not swap elements of `newArrayWithSamePower` array within the loop, then on different indexes the `if (newArrayWithSamePower[j] > newArrayWithSamePower[i])` condition will be true, thus `array` will be swapped differently. The algorithm works in place - it has to modify elements to work properly.